# When should give ax.imshow() a variable name?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginner of matplotlib, I found that the `ax.imshow()` and `im = ax.imshow()` are both used in some coding templates, so I'm confused, when should give a return name?

Comment: Did you find any application that use `im = ax.imshow()`?

Comment: Do you need access to the `AxesImage` object? If so, save it. If not, don't. If you don't know why you would need access to it, likely you don't need access to it. One (of *many*) possible use-case is if you need to replace the image data without calling imshow again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `im = ax.imshow()` when you want add something to the existing axis, for example, a colorbar. If you don't need to add anything to the axis, then it is fine to just use `ax.imshow()`. See this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-axes-axes-imshow-in-python/

Example from the link:

```
c = ax.imshow(z, cmap ='Greens', vmin = z_min,
              vmax = z_max, extent =[x.min(),
                                     x.max(),
                                     y.min(),
                                     y.max()],
              interpolation ='nearest', 
              origin ='lower')
  
fig.colorbar(c, ax = ax)
```